# Flutter push notifications with JSON body

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an flutter app with backend symfony(php), the app is integrated with firebase, and in the notification body i receive JSON something like:

```
body: {"token":"4243453","title":"Store","price":50,"currency":"GPB"}
```

I have tried to pars the data, but with no luck, my question is, is that possible in flutter to pars json data in the notification body, or that needs to be done by the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json data in the notification body. Just create a class with the expected attributes of your json and implement the deserialization.
Looking at your example json the class could be:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Message {
  final String token;
  final String title;
  final int price;
  final String currency;

  Message(this.token, this.title, this.price, this.currency);

  static Message fromJson(String source) => fromMap(json.decode(source));

  static Message fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;

    return Message(
      map['token'],
      map['title'],
      map['price'],
      map['currency'],
    );
  }
}
```

Then when you receive a notification you just have to call Message.fromJson().

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but,
`{notification: {title: Application Title, body: {"token":"534543545","store":"StoreName","price":10,"currency":"GBP"}}, data: {key: value}}` this is the full notification that i get, do i create the class with all the attribute or just the body ones ? Because i think that the parameters in the body should be in the "data" or this is okei too?

Comment: You can either create the class with all attributes and use map['body']['token'], map['data']['key']. Or you could also do it like they're doing here: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#notification-messages-with-additional-data
It's probably better to put additional data like the one in your body in the data attribute.